# Toggle SCROLL LOCK when screensaver activates

Tags: python, visual-studio, vbscript, screensaver

I wish to make an application that runs in the background at all times in windows that toggles scroll lock when my computer's screensaver enables, then toggle it back after it disables, if possible.

The reason is that I have a keyboard that lights up depending on the state of the scroll lock light. It would be cool to have the keyboard turn off the lights automatically when im not using it.

I know some code in VBscript, some in Python, and lots in VB. I have tried using a code snippet from [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/08/10/how-can-i-tell-if-the-screen-saver-is-active.aspx) and turning it into this:

```vb
strComputer = "computername"
Set wshShell =wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")

Do
  WScript.Sleep 300
  For Each objProcess In colProcesses
    If Right(objProcess.Name, 4) = ".scr" Then
      wshShell.SendKeys "{SCROLLLOCK}"
    End If 
  Next
Loop
```

which works only if the program runs when the screensaver is already on.
Please help me find out how I can make this check every 300 ticks if the screensaver is on, or tell me how in one of the other languages listed in the title.

Comment: At first glance your code doesn't look incorrect to me. It could take up to 5 minutes before it detects the screensaver but that's the only problem I see. What happens if the screensaver is started and the program already runs (and you waited the 5 minutes)?

Comment: @Syberdoor why 5 minutes?

Comment: sorry, I was confused. I somehow assumed vbscript sleep was like c-style sleep in seconds not miliseconds... forget what I said, ansgars answer below would be correct though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of a WMI query reflects the state when the query was run. It doesn't automatically refresh and thus won't pick up any processes that were launched after its initial run. Move the query inside the outer loop so it's re-run with every iteration:

```vb
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Do
  WScript.Sleep 300
  Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")
  For Each objProcess In colProcesses
    If Right(objProcess.Name, 4) = ".scr" Then
      wshShell.SendKeys "{SCROLLLOCK}"
    End If 
  Next
Loop
```

Comment: @Jared The code is meant to address the problem in your question, not to provide you with a complete script. You still need to integrate it with the rest of your code.

Comment: It worked! thanks! im just starting to use VBscript because i thought it would be both appropriate for this project and also simple and lightweight.